# database not responding on localhost

Tags: url-rewriting, database, localhost

I'm trying to work on an existing WordPress site on my Mac using MAMP. I've setup a new database using phpMyAdmin and imported the tables from the backup of the online version. I pasted this into wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

I used this command in SQL to change the URLs to localhost:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'http://www.newsiteurl.com');
```

When I go to `http://localhost` the site comes up fine; in the admin I get the dashboard and I can do things like upload and activate a theme, but I am unable to, say, upload new media (get a broken jpg image), or modify the theme – [Ultimatum](http://ultimatumtheme.com/). When I try to go to local pages on the site from the front page, I get the "The requested URL /about was not found on this server."

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try different settings in wp-config.php for WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME (e.g. `http://localhost`)?

Comment: i tried that, but i just got http://localhostlocalhost/about. I'm very new to php, so maybe i'm just being dumb!

Comment: Have you tried flushing your permalink settings?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, while convenient, let's rule out the variable of using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` trick and put in the absolute URLs.

Here are some handy snippets I use when moving a site (you may want to use these to make sure everything is the same on your install):

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.olddomain.com','http://www.newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.olddomain.com', 'http://www.newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com', 'http://www.newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com', 'http://www.newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Comment: Hi Zach, thanks for that. I'm new to WP, but I assume I delete the old code and replace it with your suggestion, modified with my URLs in wp-config.php?

Comment: Hi - ah, sorry for jumping the gun here. What I gave you above are SQL queries that you can run in phpMyAdmin (for example), replacing the `olddomain.com` and `newdomain.com` with their respective values. Once running those, it's not a bad idea to login and re-save your permalink structure to update your `.htaccess` file as well. And yes, add in your full site URL in that wp-config.php file. Thanks!

Comment: OK, just seen your reply, so feel free to ignore this: Hi Zach, I did what I suggested above, and now all I get a completely blank page in all browsers, no error message (firebug shows no content other than html, head and body tags)

Comment: What were the steps you did? Please be specific (one by one) and the actual information you entered. What were your SQL query results when you ran those?

Comment: Hang on a sec, am just trying this, will get back either way. thanks

Comment: Right: I deleted the code you gave me from wp-config.php and then ran each line through SQL. All said 0 lines affected except the "post_content" line, which said 900 rows affected. Here's that line: `code` UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.latamrob.com/', 'http://localhost/'); I just pasted the two URLs over for all the lines, so I guess thats OK. I reinstated the variable trick for now. Still getting not found in browsers. Have no idea what the rest of your reply meant in exact terms, can't even find .htaccess! Thanks for your patience

Comment: Ok - if the other said `0 lines effected` and you have over 900 other rows effected in the `post_content` line, then you'll want to investigate further in your DB to see what your older URLs are. Also, what you pasted in for the format you did for the SQL queries wasn't exactly what I gave you (so in the event it wasn't make sure you clean that up). Getting a bit outside of the support I can give you through WP Stack Exchange unfortunately as it sounds like you'll need to look a bit more into how WP deals with its permalinks (.htaccess specifically). Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's just using this Add Comment, it stripped out the httpee, colon, slash, slash. Promise i did it exactly as you said. Thanks for your help, and i'll check for other URLs. I did a quick check in TextWrangler and got more than 10,000, so I guess that'll keep me busy :)